# Set a button to invisible once clicked

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to set a button to invisible in AS3 however when the I leave the frame and come back to it the button is visible again. This is for a jeopardy game I make making for comm tech class.

Here is what I currently have:

```
a1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, a1mouseClick); 

function a1mouseClick(mouse:MouseEvent) {
    a1.visible = false;
    gotoAndStop("A1");
    trace("Going to A1");
}
```

however when it comes back to the frame with the a1 button it is visible again.

Here is my current animation: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/23938245/jeporady.fla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@fsbmain and @prototypical they are right.

> While moving through the timeline flash player can recreates sprites, movie clips and text fields, so your buttons appears visible again. To prevent recreation move all controls to separate level without key frames. If key frames are required try to set the same instance name for this button in all keyframes.

I was looking at your project, and offer a quick fix, you need to do the following:

1. Create a new layer on top to manage a few of actions availables for all frames with the following actions:

   ```
   import flash.display.DisplayObject;

   // Manages the buttons visible state 
   var buttonsStates:Object = {
       "a1":true, "b1":true, "c1":true, "d1":true, "e1":true,
       "a2":true, "b2":true, "c2":true, "d2":true, "e2":true,
       "a3":true, "b3":true, "c3":true, "d3":true, "e3":true,
       "a4":true, "b4":true, "c4":true, "d4":true, "e4":true,
       "a5":true, "b5":true, "c5":true, "d5":true, "e5":true
   };

   // Checks the buttons visibility
   function checkVisibility () {   
       for (var buttonName:String in buttonsStates)
       {
           var child:DisplayObject = this.getChildByName(buttonName);
           child.visible = buttonsStates[buttonName];
       }
   }

   // Saves the visible satatus to false
   function setVisibilityToFalse(target:*) {
       buttonsStates[target.name] = false;
       target.visible = false;
   }
   ```
2. Every time you want to check the visibility of the buttons you must call the `checkVisibility()` function. For example, every time you return to the button list.
3. Finally the event handler for each button must be like this:

   ```
   function a1mouseClick(mouse:MouseEvent) {
       setVisibilityToFalse(mouse.currentTarget); // Saves the visible state to false
       gotoAndStop("A1");
       trace("Going to A1");
   }
   ```

You can download the edited file here http://cl.ly/Lt6X

Comment: Thanks very much. It's my first time using flash so I'm no pro with it. This was a huge help :)

Answer (score 4):

While moving through the timeline flash player can recreates sprites, movie clips and text fields, so your buttons appears visible again. To prevent recreation move all controls to separate level without key frames. If key frames are required try to set the same instance name for this button in all keyframes.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a fundamental aspect of how the flash timeline and keyframes function. Once you move away from that frame, the stage instance of the content of that frame and it's properties/states are gone. When you return to that frame, the instance is created again based on the keyframe contents.

I think the best solution given your current approach is to put the main board persistent throughout all the frames. You can do that by creating a layer for it, and have it's keyframe extend from frame 2 to frame 27. However, your next issue will be adjusting visibility of all the elements on that screen when you don't want them visible.

My suggestion would be to put all the elements of that screen into a movieclip symbol of it's own and add that movieclip, and all code for it's listeners,  to this new layer you created. For example you might name that instance - main_board and therefore you could modify it's visibility with `main_board.visible` property. If you did choose that solution, you would need to modify all the code on that frame to use that instance name as well ie :

```
main_board.a1.visible = false;
```

Also, you'd need to modify all you addEventListener lines as well :

```
main_board.a1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, a1mouseClick);
```

Your approach for this game could be greatly simplified, but even further beyond the scope of this question than I have already gone!